# No Retrofit Annotation Found For Parameter #1

Tags: android, kotlin

**Here is my interface code. But it is giving error at @Field**

```
@POST("login")
    @FormUrlEncoded
    fun login(@Field email : String, password: String) : Call<LoginResponse>
```

**Calling Function:**

```
private fun login() {

    val callback = object : MyCallback<LoginResponse>() {

        override fun onSuccess(response: LoginResponse) {
            Log.d("family", "Login Success.")
        }

        override fun onFail(error: ErrorModel) {
            Log.d("family", "Login Failed.")
        }
    }

    RestClientManager.getInstance(context).login("jhon@family-live.com", "123456789", callback)
}
```

**Here is my error : 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No Retrofit annotation found. (parameter #1)
        for method RestService.login**

Comment: if I add **@Field** it shows an error **not value passed for parameter 'value'.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the api call on Postman and check the fields name in proper manner and put the field name in bracket which will assign value to that field. read the official [documentation](https://square.github.io/retrofit/) URL manipulation.

```
@POST("login")
@FormUrlEncoded
fun login(@Field("email") email : String, @Field("password") password: String) : Call<LoginResponse>
```

Comment: It works but now i'm getting another problem which is the error from server side.Everything is correct but i don't know why it is happening. 
**Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=500, message=Internal Server Error, url=http://family-live.herokuapp.com/api/v1/users/login}**

Comment: @AhmadRehan Please explain your problem

Answer (score 1):

Use This

```
@POST("login")
@FormUrlEncoded
fun login(@Field email : String, @Field password: String) : Call<LoginResponse>
```

Comment: Thanks, but it is requiring **@Field** value

Comment: The answer from @Ashish https://stackoverflow.com/a/58569336/11520411 is correct one